# Decoding an Encrypted Authorization/Error message in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-policies

Some actions that involve IAM permissions may return a Client.UnauthorizedOperation responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can decrypt the message from the CLI using the following command:

```
$> aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message <encoded message from error>
```

This will give you an output that looks like:

```
{"allowed":false,"explicitDeny":false,"matchedStatements":{"items":[]},"failures":{"items":[]},"context":{"principal":{"id":"APOZIAANAVSK6I6FK2RQI:i-66c78ee7","arn":"arn:aws:sts::<aws-account-id>:assumed-role/my-role-ec2/i-123456e7"},"action":"iam:PassRole","resource":"arn:aws:iam::<aws-account-id>:role/my-role-ec2","conditions":{"items":[]}}}
```

The error message is actually encoded JSON inside `""`, by default the embedded quotes (`"`) are escaped as `\"`; to facilitate reading the error, extract the message portion and use a text editor to replace `\"` with `"`.

Answer (score 1):

To get it more readable:

```
aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message \
[the_message] | jq .DecodedMessage -r | jq
```

If you don't have jq you can take it e.g. from here https://stedolan.github.io/jq

Answer (score 0):

Run this below code for easier reading of the error in JSON format.

```
aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message  <encode_message> --query DecodedMessage --output text | jq '.'
```